# calculating Volume in a unit cube

Tags: calculus

Consider the unit cube in the positive octant of the XYZ system.Define a domain $D$ as : $$ D=\{(x,y,z):x \geq y\geq z  \quad\text{and} \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1,0 \leq y \leq 1,0 \leq z \leq 1\}$$How do we compute the volume of $D$ with the help of  a multiple integral?Thanking you in anticipation for any hints/answers!

Comment: You don't need really any integral to compute the volume. Apart from a set of volume $0$, you can decompose the unit cube into 6 regions

$$x \ge y \ge z,\; x \ge z \ge y,\; y \ge z \ge x,\; y \ge x \ge z,\; z \ge x \ge y,\; z \ge y \ge x$$
which have same volume by symmetry. The volume you seek is simply $\frac16$ of the cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume is $$
D = \int_{0}^1\left[\int_{0}^x\left\{\int_{0}^y 1 \; {\rm d} z\right\}{\rm d} y\right] {\rm d} x\\
= \int_{0}^1\left[\int_{0}^x y \;{\rm d} y\right] {\rm d} x \\
= \int_{0}^1 \frac12 x^2 {\rm d} x = \frac16\\
$$